Python: Issue injecting javascript in new page of the same window
I would like to capture the names,id,...etc of clicked controls (input text, button,..etc) of a page (facebook.com for example). For that I am injecting a script to the page code using selenium (see code below). Everything works fine for the first open page. However, when I move to a new page by clicking on a link (for example: Create a Page: https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/?ref_type=registration_form) the script is not injected into the new open page. The code is below:
from selenium import webdriver

# Initialize the Firefox WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Open the webpage
url = "https://www.facebook.com"  # Replace with the URL of the webpage you want to interact with
driver.get(url)

# JavaScript code to inject
js_code = """
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    // Function to generate CSS selector for the element
    function getCssSelector(el) {
        if (!(el instanceof Element)) return;
        var path = [];
        while (el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            var selector = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if (el.id) {
                selector += '#' + el.id;
                path.unshift(selector);
                break;
            } else {
                var sib = el, nth = 1;
                while (sib = el.previousElementSibling) {
                    if (sib.nodeName.toLowerCase() == selector)
                        nth++;
                }
                if (nth != 1)
                    selector += ":nth-of-type("+nth+")";
            }
            path.unshift(selector);
            el = el.parentNode;
        }
        return path.join(" > ");
    }

    // Function to extract href attribute value from the clicked link
    function getHref(el) {
        if (!(el instanceof HTMLAnchorElement)) return;
        return el.href;
    }

    // Generate CSS selector for the clicked element
    var cssSelector = getCssSelector(target);

    // If the clicked element is a link, extract the href attribute value
    var href = getHref(target);

    // Print information about the clicked element
    var elementInfo = {
        tagName: target.tagName,
        id: target.id,
        className: target.className,
        type: target.type,
        cssSelector: cssSelector,
        href: href
    };
    console.log('Clicked Element:', elementInfo);
    alert(JSON.stringify(elementInfo));
});
"""

# Function to inject the click listener JavaScript code
def inject_click_listener_script():
    driver.execute_script(js_code)

# Inject the click listener script on the initial page
inject_click_listener_script()

# Wait for user interactions
print("Please click on any element on the webpage. Press Enter when done...")
input()

# Function to wait for the page to finish loading and inject the script again
def wait_and_inject_script():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))
    inject_click_listener_script()

# Monitor for page changes within the same window
while True:
    # Check if the user wants to exit
    exit_command = input("Press Enter to continue, or type 'exit' to quit: ")
    if exit_command.lower() == "exit":
        break

    # Execute the script on the new page
    wait_and_inject_script()

# Quit the driver
driver.quit()

it seems that the condition WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))
is never meet.
Any advice or help is appreciated.

You don't have to wait, body will be there when driver.get() returns.
